# Filtering by non-null values on a nested array does not return results

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
    country: "NL",
    product: "1583392",
    prices: [{
        price: 220.00,
        rrp: 250.00,
        version: 10
    }, {
        price: null,
        rrp: 250.00,
        version: 9
    }]
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is find this document using the `country` and `product`, but only if the `price` of the first entry in `prices` is **not null**. So what I'm trying to use is this query, but it returns no result:

```
{ country: "NL", product: "1583392", "prices.0.price": { $ne: null } }
    => document not found (?)
```

I then tested some other queries, where some lead to unexpected results:

```
{ country: "NL", product: "1583392", "prices.0.price": { $eq: null }}
    => document found (?)

{ country: "NL", product: "1583392", "prices.0.price": null }
    => document found (?)

{ country: "NL", product: "1583392", "prices.0.price": 220.00 }
    => document found

{ country: "NL", product: "1583392", "prices.0.rrp": null }
    => document found (?)

{ country: "NL", product: "1583392", "prices.0.rrp": 250.00 }
    => document found
```

Is there any way to match a field of a specific item in a nested array by null?

(Using `$elemMatch` seems to work correctly, but I need to match only the first nested item.)

Comment: I think you're hitting on a couple of nuanced parts of the language, specifically as it pertains to nulls in arrays, negations in arrays and ambiguity with what ".0" means. If your solution below works then it seems reasonable concise. The only thing I'd ask is if you'd want flip the query around. If the value is present is it always a positive number? Perhaps `gt: 0` would work instead?

Comment: @user20042973 You're right, just tested your approach and `gt: 0` would work in the same way, if that is the constraint. Unfortunately my example is over simplified and I have fields of other types too. Checking for the "not null" type it is applicable to any type.

Answer (score 1):

Querying by $type works.

```
{ country: "NL", product: "1583392", "prices.0.price": { $not: { $type: 10 } } }
```

Type `10` is the [BSON type](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) for `null`.